# Maximise left and maximise right for a WIN32 application

Tags: windows, winapi, window, maximize, showwindow

I am creating a WIN32 application. Is there a way I can change the window so that it can maximise to the left or right, as if you pressed win + right arrow or win + left arrow?

I've tried using the ShowWindow() method, but none of the parameters accept left or right maximisation. I've also tried using AdjustWindowRect() using the following code:

```
AdjustWindowRect(&wr, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, TRUE);    // adjust the window
```

where wr is of type RECT, however this does not seem to change the window size or position.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'AdjustWindowRect' only "Calculates the required size of the window rectangle".

Use the [MoveWindow function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For example, to move the left border of the window to the left edge of the screen:

```
RECT rc;
GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rc);
MoveWindow(hWnd, 0, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom - rc.top, TRUE);
```